# Como fazer uma busca em um app usando AngularJS com passagem de parâmetro de forma correta?

Tags: sql, angularjs, query

Como fazer uma busca em um app usando AngularJS com passagem de parâmetro de forma correta, quando falo de forma correta refiro a evitar Injeção de SQL.

Por Exemplo; o parâmetro `var parameters = "joao";` na query abaixo.

```
self.searchAll = function(nameSearch){
  var parameters = "joao";

  return DBA.query('SELECT id, name FROM users WHERE name  ?', parameters)
    .then(function(result){
      return DBA.getAll(result);
    });
}
```

Comment: Não seria melhor (e mais seguro) deixar a declaração da `query` somente no arquivo que estiver em seu servidor, ao invés de ter ele explicito no FrontEnd? No caso, fazer apenas uma chamada de função e enviar somente os parâmetros?

Comment: @CelsomTrindade, Claro que seria, mas gostaria de saber se tem alguma solução no FrontEnd para isso.

Comment: Soluções de frontend como a mencionada no seu exemplo revelam a sua estrutura de banco para usuários maliciosos, aumentando assim a 'superfície exposta' da sua aplicação, algo não exatamente recomendável do ponto de vista de segurança.

Comment: o que é DBA ? é um rest que recebe uma query como parâmetro ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não é seguro e muito menos aconselhável deixar a query exposta dessa forma.

Aconselho-te a trabalhar com [RESTful](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/REST). Caso trabalhe com PHP, você pode usar um `microframework` para isso. Eu utilizo e gosto bastante do [Slim Framework](http://www.slimframework.com/).

Em meus projetos, normalmente sigo essa estrutura:

No exemplo abaixo, faço um Controller (usuario.controller.js), que envia a solicitação para um Service (service.js) e este por sua vez retorna os dados que foram solicitados ao backend da aplicação (/app/usuarios/index.php).

```
# usuario.controller.js
...
angular.controller('UsuarioCtrl', Usuario);
...
function Usuario($scope,$stateParams,api) {

    api.getUsuario($stateParams.id).success(function(data){
        $scope.usuario = data.usuario;
    });

}
...


# service.js
...
angular.service('api', Api);
...
function Api($http,$rootScope) {

    this.getUsuario = function (id) {
        return $http.get("/app/api/usuarios/"+ id) || [];
    };
}
...


# /app/usuarios/index.php
...
function getUsuario($id){

    $sql = "
        SELECT id,nome,email
        FROM usuarios
        WHERE id = :id
    ";
    try {
        $con = getConnection();
        $stmt = $con->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute(array('id' => $id));
        $usuario = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

        echo json_encode(array("usuario"=>$usuario[0]));
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo '{"error":"' . $e->getMessage() . '"}';
    }
}
...
```